# Access CosmosDB table from FunctionApp

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to read a table from From function app but didn't come across any API which lets function app to interact with CosmosDB table.

However this what i find :

```
public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,
        HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS),@TableInput(name = "items",
        tableName = "mytablename",
        partitionKey = "myparkey",
        connection = "myconnvarname") MyItem[] items, HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context)
```

But there is compile time error in this code.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

If you can access Azure Cosmos Table API in Azure java function, we can use [Azure Table Storage input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---java-example) to access Azure Cosmos DB Table API. For example

1. Update function.json. Add table input binding to json file

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "..\\testfun-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "testfun.Function.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "req",
    "methods" : [ "GET", "POST" ]
  }, {
    "type" : "table",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "users",
    "connection" : "MyConn",// your Cosmos DB table API connection string
    "tableName" : "User"// your table name
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "$return"
  } ]
}
```

2. Update your code
   a. Create a Class which you want to return from Cosmos DB

   ```
    class User{

    public String PartitionKey;



    public String RowKey;
    public String Age;

    public String getPartitionKey() {
        return PartitionKey;
    }

    public void setPartitionKey(String partitionKey) {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey;
    }

    public String getRowKey() {
        return RowKey;
    }

    public void setRowKey(String rowKey) {
        RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        Age = age;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "PartitionKey='" + PartitionKey + '\'' +
                ", RowKey='" + RowKey + '\'' +
                ", Age='" + Age + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


   }
   ```

   b. Update function. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---java-example

   ```
   @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
   public HttpResponseMessage run(
           @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
           @TableInput(name = "users",
                   tableName = "User",
                   connection = "MyConn") User[] users,final ExecutionContext context)  {
       context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");


       return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello" + "\n" +users[0].toString()).build();


   }
   ```
3. Test

[image]
[image]

Comment: @subodh Do you have any other concerns?